# Join statements/primary and foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have an ER diagram over a database which handles parking.
There is a user table, car table, payment table and contact info table.

[image]

I understand how to join one to one relationships. But how can we make a statement that returns the username (this is lacking in the diagram, imagine its in the userinfo table) of the users, with all the cars they own. There is a one too many relationshop between user_info and user_car. But it is not a requirement that users also have a car. Its optional.

So the result of the query should be looking like:

A table listing all the users in the system, including those who does not own a car (NULL value). And is it possible to order the users by their username?

So what kind of query is required for such a result?

Im fairly new to MySQL please correct me if I have made any wrong statements.
Greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks Beforehand

Comment: What have yo tried so far?

Comment: Use left join plus order by

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I have tried something like this: SELECT username.userinfo, make.user_car, model.user_car, year.user_car, license_plate.user_car FROM user_info INNER JOIN user_car ON user_info.user_id = user_car.license_plate;

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto dont know if this is the correct way of doing it, if it works or if NULL values are represented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT ui.username, uc.make, uc.model, uc.year, uc.license_plate
FROM user_info ui
LEFT JOIN user_car uc ON ui.user_id = uc.user_info_user_id;
```

This will show alluser from `user_info`, even if they have no cars, showing `NULL` in tha car's columns. If you want to omit these, just remove `LEFT` from `LEFT JOIN` (or replace with `INNER JOIN`)...

Comment: Aha. Thank you very much.